# How to set interface method between two viewController to pass paramter in Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created Window based application, root controller as Tab Bar controller. One Tab bar has Navigation controller.

Navigation controller's ViewControlller implementation, I am pushing Viewcontroller.

I am looking to pass parameter from Navigation Controller's View controller to pushed View Controller.

I have tried to pass as per below method.

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController:UIViewController{
   NSString *String;
}
@property(copy, nonatomic)NSString *String;
@end
//ViewController.m 
 #import "ViewController1.h"

 ViewController1 *level1view = [[ViewController alloc]init];
 level1view.hideBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
 level1view.theString = String;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:level1view animated:YES];
 [level1view release]; 

//ViewController1.h
NSString *theString;

@property(copy, nonatomic)NSString *theString;
```

This is working fine. but I want to pass more than one parameter like Integer and UITextFiled Values so how to do that?

Is there any Apple Doc that I can get idea about this?

Thanks,

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous questions.  More people will want to help you.  Also please indent your code by 4 spaces so that it will be properly formatted.  See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use NSUserDefaults instead, just like:

```
    NSUserDefaults *UserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[UserDefaults setInteger:... forKey:@"KEY"];
```

and in the other controller:

```
    NSUserDefaults *UserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
...= [UserDefaults integerForKey:@"KEY"];
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to pass it one by one like this only but make sure that you pass it all after

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:level1view animated:YES];
```

this line... Otherwise sometimes it won't reflect

So interchange

```
level1view.theString = String; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:level1view animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:level1view animated:YES]; 
level1view.theString = String;
```

Comment: thanks, Mihir,
If I set interface method like -(void)loadData:(NSString)string in pushed view controller. Then I use that to pass Object values like [level1view loadData:String];

Which is proper way to pass object values ?
Thanks,

[

Comment: it seems like it works only i pass it before i push the view controller.